# Why ng-enter ng-leave action animation classes are not added in angular?

Tags: css, angular, animation, angular-ng-if

I want animation based on DOM manipulation using ngIf.
There are classes(ng-enter and ng-leave) which were being applied in AngularJS Framework using ngAnimate where we can hook animation.
Why they are not added to Angular.

Is there any other way we can have CSS Animation (not Web API animation) in Angular when DOM removal event is occured using ngIf.

Comment: You have much better way to do it than "ngAnimate", more information : https://angular.io/guide/animations

Comment: but that is dependent on the Web API animation not CSS animation.

Comment: `ngIf` will not add the element to the DOM, maybe you can try `ngShow` instead of `ngIf`. `NgShow` is adding the element to the `dom` with display none.

Comment: if the value for ngIf change from false to true. Element will be added to the DOM.